# how do i bring multiline csv file into single line using python

Tags: python

Input: csv file.
sample data

```
id,name,gnd,address,second_name.
"100","xx","m","plot y zzzz city","zx
yddfe"
```

Output:csv file.

```
id,name,gnd,address,second_name.
"100","xx","m","plot y zzzz city","zxyddfe"
```

In source file last column data is broken into two lines i want into single line to load the data.

I tried with:

```
import csv

with open("out.csv","w") as fout:
   with open("sample.csv")as f:
    firsttline = ""
    for line in f:
       if not line.startswith('"'):continue
       else:
          line = line.rstrip('\n')
          firstline = firstline + '\n'+ line
    print >> fout, firstline
    with open ("out.csv") as fin:
         with open("out1.csv","w") as fout1:
            for line in fin:
                if not line.isspace():
                fout1.write(line)
```

After using this code I am not getting proper record count. A few of the columns' data is missing. Please assist me.

Comment: By doing the `continue` you will miss part of your data. `yddfe` in this example. Do `firstline = firstline + line.rstrip('\n')` without the `\n` in between.

Comment: Why don't you use the csv module to automatically process the new line inside a quoted field?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data.csv')
```

output looks like

```
    name gnd           address  second_name.
id                                          
100   xx   m  plot y zzzz city  zx\r\n yddfe
```

More information about [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). 
It's very easy to read and write `.csv`-files with pandas. I would always prefer them instead of the `csv` library.

Comment: with out using pandas i need a solution is there any other approach?

Comment: `pandas` is an overkill

Comment: But very easy to use